# How to add custom ListView to WorkflowMultiBranchProject generated by Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin?

Tags: jenkins, groovy, multibranch-pipeline

We currently have custom jobs which are generated from templates. These jobs include stuff like deployment. They are generated per (Bitbucket) project.

But what we'd really like to do is to add custom views (e.g. for deployment) to the WorkflowMultiBranchProject "jobs" which are automatically generated by the Bitbucket Branch Source Plugin (i.e. the same Bitbucket projects we already have deploy jobs for).

I've tried to simply add a new ListView to my existing (generated) job/project but it doesn't work.

```
import hudson.model.ListView
import jenkins.model.Jenkins
import jenkins.branch.OrganizationFolder

def jenkins = Jenkins.get()
def mp = jenkins.getItemByFullName('my-project', OrganizationFolder.class)
def tp = mp.getItem('test-project')
println tp.getViews()
def lv = new ListView('test-deploy')
tp.addView(lv)
jenkins.reload()
```

Calling `getViews()` gives me elements of type `jenkins.branch.MultiBranchProjectViewHolder$ViewImpl`. Looking at the [api documentation](https://javadoc.jenkins.io/plugin/workflow-multibranch/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/multibranch/WorkflowMultiBranchProject.html) of `WorkflowMultiBranchProject` I thought I could simply use `addView()` but it doesn't do anything.